# MVC5 Dropdown default value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, cookies

On every page of my website, I have a dropdown which contains different language cultures, I am trying to set the default value of the dropdown with the current string within the users cookies.

As you can see below, the default parameter of `SelectList` is `Request.Cookies("_culture").Value)` but on every request the dropdown resets to index 0.

```
@Using Html.BeginForm("GetCulture", "Base", FormMethod.Post, New With { _
   .id = "CultureForm"
})
   @Html.DropDownList("Culture", _
   New SelectList(ViewBag.Culture, "Key", "Value", Request.Cookies("_culture").Value), _
   New With { _
      .class = "form-control lang-toggle hidden-xs", _
      .onchange = "document.getElementById('CultureForm').submit();"
   } _
)
End Using
```

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong? Is there something about the default parameter I should know about? I can confirm the the value in `Request.Cookies("_culture").Value)` is also within the html `select > option` values.

Answer (score 0):

So the error was a complete waste of time, here is what was wrong for those who run into the same error:

The controls cannot have the same name as a key within the ViewBag

So `@Html.DropDownList("Culture" ...)` and `ViewBag.Culture` causes a conflict and results in the default not being set.

Comment: Yep, one reason to always use DropDownListFor ;)

Comment: I agree, but making a model for one dropdown seems silly. That's like moving a local variable into a separate object.